# Spring saml sets UserDetails in details object whereas normal form login sets it in principal

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security, spring-saml

How can I read the principal object in jsp based on authentication type? Or maybe check the type of object?
Issue is Spring SAML sets username in Authentication.principal, and the UserDetails object in Authentication.details

So how can I switch between principal and details in jsp to fetch the user data?
I figured out the following:

```
    <sec:authentication var="user" property="principal"/>
    <c:if test="${user.getClass().simpleName == 'String'}">
        <sec:authentication var="user" property="details"/>
        <label>${user.userCompany}</label>
    </c:if>
<c:if test="${user.getClass().simpleName != 'String'}">
        <sec:authentication var="user" property="principal"/>
        <label>${user.userCompany}</label>
</c:if>
```

But in this case I will have to repeat html tags, which I don't want to as it will lead to a lot of html duplicity. 
Or how can I read the entire Authentication object in jsp? 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of r&d, found the solution as below:

```
<sec:authentication var="userDetail" property="principal"/>
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${userDetail.getClass().simpleName == 'String'}">
                                    <sec:authentication var="user" property="details"/>
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <sec:authentication var="user" property="principal"/>
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
```

I think this will do, until someone tells something better.